# How to pass date and id through url in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass date and id through url, but getting an error, I have passed just id before and I usually do it like this.

```
path('user_payment_menu/<int:pk>/',user_payment_menu, name='user_payment_menu'),
```

but now I want date to pass after int:pk/ but when I add date after a slash I am getting an error.

Comment: How did you pass the date?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to define a `date` is with a custom path converter. You can implement this with:

```
# app_name/converters.py

class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}'
    format = '%Y-%m-%d'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, self.format).date()

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value.strftime(self.format)
```

Then you can register the format and use the `<date:…>` path converter:

```
# app_name/urls.py

from django.urls import path, register_converter
from app_name.converters import DateConverter
from app_name.views import user_payment_menu

register_converter(DateConverter, 'date')

urlpatterns = [
    path('user_payment_menu/<int:pk>/<date:mydate>/',user_payment_menu, name='user_payment_menu'),
```

then in the view you define an extra attribute that will contain the `date` as a `date` object:

```
# app_name/views.py

def user_payment_menu(request, pk, mydate):
    # …
```

You can use a `date` object when generating a URL, for example with:

```
{% url 'user_payment_menu' pk=somepk mydate=somedate %}
```

Comment: Add `from datetime import datetime` to converters.py if datetime doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

```py
path('user_payment_menu/<int:pk>/<str:date>',user_payment_menu, name='user_payment_menu'),
```

and you can use it like that:

```py
reverse('user_payment_menu', args=[1, str(date.today()])
```